# Google Earth Engine timeseries chart

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, graph

Using [this](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2903910f90b5e976a63f1272ad249b12) Google Earth Engine code I am trying to create a line graph of the data for the specified date range. The result I got is not a continuous line graph and the exported value shows undefined:0. How can I get continuous line graph with the proper value? also a request to the forum that how can I incorporate several city points in one graph. Here I have taken only one city point
The code is written as

```
var city1 = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([-93.881640625, 37.391718430950796]),
   city2 = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([-106.27421875, 33.71035637052483]),
   city3 = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Point([-117.436328125, 39.7618477958936]),
   city4 = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.Point([-95.5515625, 29.74978297462196]),
   city5 = /* color: #ffc82d */ee.Geometry.Point([-115.151171875, 36.15978520358036]);



// get the data
var y2019 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2")
             .filterDate("2019-01-01","2019-12-30");
// Select the NO2 column number density.
var times2019 = y2019
   .select("NO2_column_number_density")
// Create a time series chart.
var TimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
   times2019, city1, ee.Reducer.mean(), "NO2_column_number_density", 100, 'system:time_start', 'label')
       .setChartType('ScatterChart')
       .setOptions({
         title: 'NO2 Timeseries',
         vAxis: {title: 'NO2'},
         lineWidth: 1,
         pointSize: 4,
         series: {
           1: {color: '0000FF'}  
}});

// Display.
print(TimeSeries);
```

[image: Time series graph]

Comment: This code isn't reproducible because we don't have access to `city1`. Also, please limit questions to one specific question, and save other questions fo either googling or a separate, specific question.

Comment: @JepsonNomad I have added the city points.

Answer (score 3):

Set the argument `interpolateNulls` of the options of the chart to true. By default, that is false. Make sure you put this argument before the `series` argument:

```
// Create a time series chart.
var TimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    times2019, city1, ee.Reducer.mean(), "NO2_column_number_density", 200, 
    'system:time_start', 'label')
        .setChartType('ScatterChart')
        .setOptions({
          interpolateNulls: true,
          title: 'NO2 Timeseries',
          vAxis: {title: 'NO2'},
          lineWidth: 1,
                    pointSize: 4,
                    series: {
            1: {color: '0000FF'}  ,
          }});
```

To get the data as a CSV, use `Export.table.toDrive` and make a featurecollection of the data (using `reduceRegion()` or `reduceRegions()` for multiple goemetries):

```
// filter to region
var filtCol = times2019.filterBounds(city1);

// export to CSV
var data = ee.FeatureCollection(filtCol.map(function(image){
  return ee.Feature(null, image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), city1, 200))
             .set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
}));
print(data)

// export directly as CSV
Export.table.toDrive({collection: data, 
                      description: 'YOURDESCRIPTION', 
                      fileFormat: 'CSV', 
                      selectors: ['NO2_column_number_density', 'system:time_start']})
```

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7b4c51b28b888e1a045dbab69888c0d8)

Comment: The graph looks fine but the exported csv file shows '0' and blank. what is the probable solution to get that values.

Comment: See my edit. You see 0 values probably by some rounding of values occurring on the backend when downloading a CSV from the graph directly.